# How to fix huge amount of commits after rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I had a fairly old branch and I tried to rebase it to master. I think I messed up really bad, can someone help me on how to fix it? Here is what I did:

1. I used `git rebase origin/master`. VSCode showed that there are 4 commits to pull, and 25k to push
2. I checked the status with `git status`. The feature branch commits were on top of the master commits.
3. I pulled using `git pull`, and a merge commit got created on top of all others (saw that with `git status` afterwards)
4. I pushed using `git push --force-with-lease`

Now the GitHub PR shows all those commits and thousands of changes, and I don't know how to fix it. In my previous company we only used `git merge` so this entire approach is very new to me.

Thank you!

Comment: Why did you pull? What did you pull?

Comment: You already pushed the 25k commits, so I would say the PR is forfeit. Close it. Save your changes in a backup. Clone the repo again and re-apply your changes and make it a separate PR without this mistake. It's less work compared to properly repairing this. Usually you would fetch before you rebase, not pull after you rebase.

Comment: Probably the only mistake was step #3 which you should not have done. Skipping that you probably should have just force pushed as in step 4. Having 25K commits to push isn't out of line if your "fairly old branch" was 25K commits out of date. That being said, the last part about the PR showing thousands of changes doesn't really make sense to me, unless you were looking at what changed from one push to the next. But from the PR's point of view the same files and changes should have been showing in the PR both before and after the push, even with the extra merge commit.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix it. What I did:

1. `git reflog` to identify what commit I was on. It was the one before `rebase (start)`, and in my case - `HEAD@{10}`
2. `git reset --hard HEAD@{10}`
3. All the extra commits (25k in my case) got listed as difference from the remote branch, and VSCode was prompting me to pull them
4. Instead, I used `git push origin <branch-name> --force`
5. All is in sync in the local branch, and the PR shows only the 4 commits made by me

Comment: Almost the same as my answer, except that you went even further and did the _right_ thing after having done the wrong thing. And you just overwrote the PR instead of making a new one. But it amounts to much the same thing. :)

Comment: That was a huge stress, not gonna lie. Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: Rule 1 of Git: almost everything is undoable!

Comment: @matt well, except: reset, clean, rebase --abort, rm -f, … ;) Everything that was committed at least once is recoverable (so anything that was "known" to Git; "staged" falls in this category too)

Comment: @knittl 100%, that's why I said "almost". One good clean or rm can ruin your day, or more... much more...

Answer (score 1):

At the GitHub end, delete (close) the "bad" PR that you just made.

At your end, whip out the `reflog` and find the commit *before* the rebase. On your branch, `reset --hard` to that commit.

You have now undone everything described in your question.